# onSkuDetailsResponse returns an empty product list OCCASIONALLY

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

I use e BillingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsAsync) to load products, but occasionally I receive an empty list from onSkuDetailsResponse(onProductDetailsResponse), even though the billingResult is okay. Why is this happening?

There is a probability of approximately 0.1% that this situation may occur.

```
   private int loadProductsNew(LuaState L) {
    if (!initSuccessful()) {
        Log.w("Corona", "Please call init before trying to load products.");
        return 0;
    }

    int managedProductsTableIndex = 1;
    int listenerIndex = 2;

    final List<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    final HashSet<String> managedProducts = new HashSet<String>();
    if (L.isTable(managedProductsTableIndex)) {
        int managedProductsLength = L.length(managedProductsTableIndex);
        for (int i = 1; i <= managedProductsLength; i++) {
            L.rawGet(managedProductsTableIndex, i);
            if (L.type(-1) == LuaType.STRING) {
                String id = L.toString(-1);
                managedProducts.add(id);
                productList.add(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                        .setProductId(id).build());
            }
            L.pop(1);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Corona", "Missing product table to store.loadProducts");
    }

    final HashSet<String> subscriptionProducts = new HashSet<String>();
    if (!CoronaLua.isListener(L, listenerIndex, "productList") && L.isTable(listenerIndex)) {
        int subscriptionProductsLength = L.length(listenerIndex);
        for (int i = 1; i <= subscriptionProductsLength; i++) {
            L.rawGet(listenerIndex, i);
            if (L.type(-1) == LuaType.STRING) {
                String id = L.toString(-1);
                subscriptionProducts.add(id);
                productList.add(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                        .setProductId(id).build());
            }
            L.pop(1);
        }
        listenerIndex++;
    }

    final int listener = CoronaLua.isListener(L, listenerIndex, "productList") ? CoronaLua.newRef(L, listenerIndex) : CoronaLua.REFNIL;

    QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(productList)
            .build();
    fBillingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
        public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
            if (productDetailsList != null) {
                // Process the result
                for (ProductDetails details : productDetailsList) {
                    fCachedSKUDetails.put(details.getProductId(), details);
                }
                fDispatcher.send(new ProductListRuntimeTask(productDetailsList, managedProducts, subscriptionProducts, billingResult, listener));
            }
        }
    });

    return 0;
}

private int loadProductsOld(LuaState L) {
    if (!initSuccessful()) {
        Log.w("Corona", "Please call init before trying to load products.");
        return 0;
    }

    int managedProductsTableIndex = 1;
    int listenerIndex = 2;

    final HashSet<String> managedProducts = new HashSet<String>();
    if (L.isTable(managedProductsTableIndex)) {
        int managedProductsLength = L.length(managedProductsTableIndex);
        for (int i = 1; i <= managedProductsLength; i++) {
            L.rawGet(managedProductsTableIndex, i);
            if (L.type(-1) == LuaType.STRING) {
                managedProducts.add(L.toString(-1));
            }
            L.pop(1);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Corona", "Missing product table to store.loadProducts");
    }

    final HashSet<String> subscriptionProducts = new HashSet<String>();
    if (!CoronaLua.isListener(L, listenerIndex, "productList") && L.isTable(listenerIndex)) {
        int subscriptionProductsLength = L.length(listenerIndex);
        for (int i = 1; i <= subscriptionProductsLength; i++) {
            L.rawGet(listenerIndex, i);
            if (L.type(-1) == LuaType.STRING) {
                subscriptionProducts.add(L.toString(-1));
            }
            L.pop(1);
        }
        listenerIndex++;
    }

    final int listener = CoronaLua.isListener(L, listenerIndex, "productList") ? CoronaLua.newRef(L, listenerIndex) : CoronaLua.REFNIL;
    final List<SkuDetails> allSkus = new ArrayList<SkuDetails>();
    final BillingResult.Builder result = BillingResult.newBuilder().setResponseCode(BillingResponseCode.OK);

    final BillingUtils.SynchronizedWaiter waiter = new BillingUtils.SynchronizedWaiter();
    final SkuDetailsResponseListener responder = new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> list) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() != BillingResponseCode.OK && result.build().getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                result.setResponseCode(billingResult.getResponseCode());
                result.setDebugMessage(billingResult.getDebugMessage());
            }
            if (list != null) {
                allSkus.addAll(list);
                for (SkuDetails details : list) {
                    fCachedSKUDetailsOld.put(details.getSku(), details);
                }
            }
            waiter.Hit();
        }
    };

    int tasks = 0;
    if (!managedProducts.isEmpty()) {
        tasks++;
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(managedProducts);
        SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(l).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();
        fBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, responder);
    }
    if (!subscriptionProducts.isEmpty()) {
        tasks++;
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(subscriptionProducts);
        SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(l).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).build();
        fBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, responder);
    }

    waiter.Set(tasks, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fDispatcher.send(new ProductListRuntimeTaskOld(allSkus, managedProducts, subscriptionProducts, result.build(), listener));
        }
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add some code please so we can read and may find any issue